# n an array of N elements calculate its mean and count the number sub array of N-2 elements that have same mean

Tags: c

The below code is getting TLE error i.e Time limit Exceeded Error. I am finding it difficult to solve it without using nested for loops.Can someone tell a faster logic or can improve this code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
    int mean(int arr[],int n,int b){             
        int m,s=0;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            s=arr[i]+s;
        }
        m=s/b;
        return m;
    }
    int main(void) {
        int t;
        scanf("%d",&t);
        while(t){
            int n;
            scanf("%d",&n);
            int arr[n];
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
                scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
            int x,c=0;
            int m=mean(arr,n,n);
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
                for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++){       
                    int a=arr[i];
                    int b=arr[j];
                    arr[i]=0;
                    arr[j]=0;
                    x=mean(arr,n,n-2);
                    if(x==m)
                        c++;
                    arr[i]=a;
                    arr[j]=b;
                }
            }
            printf("%d\n",c);
            t--;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The single-letter variable names make the code hard to read.  Use more informative names to help readers understand what your code is doing.

Always assume input is erroneous or even hostile - *never* ignore the return value from `scanf()`.  In fact, prefer not to use `scanf()` at all, unless you're going to give up completely on standard input when it fails.

Why does `mean()` return an `int()`?  It's unlikely that the mean will be an exact integer.

You should improve the algorithm so that scales better.  Instead of calling `mean()` on the whole `n-2` subarray in the inner loop, keep a track of the running sum of those elements.  That can be updated linearly.  And there's no need to divide the sum each time around - just multiply up before you start, and then you just need to compare against the target sum.

Or even simpler - use your mathematical reasoning to realise that the problem is really a search for two elements whose mean is that of the entire array - i.e. we're looking for an `a` and `b` such that `(a + b) * n / 2 == Σx`.  That is then just a variation on the well-known "2-sum" problem.